# ERROR - Trying to get property of non-object - in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I am getting the problem when i fetch categorey name from categorey table ..
code here ..

Thanks.

```
 public function viewProducts(){

     $products = Product::get();
     $products = json_decode(json_encode($products));

     foreach($products as $key => $val){
        $category_name = Category::where(['id'=>$val->category_id])->first();
        $products[$key]->category_name= $category_name->name;
     }
     echo "<pre>";print_r($products);die;

     return view('admin.products.view_products')->with(compact('products'));
}
```

ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property of non-object[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4ql7.png)

Answer (score 1):

The error is straight forward. You haven't gotten any objects of $category_name variable and you're trying to access to the value of the name property. Which is not defined because there's no object.

Add a simple condition to fix it like this

```
public function viewProducts(){
  $products = Product::get();
  $products = json_decode(json_encode($products));

  foreach($products as $key => $val){
    $category_name = Category::where(['id'=>$val->category_id])->first();
      if($category_name != null){
        $products[$key]->category_name= $category_name->name;
      }
    }
  echo "<pre>";print_r($products);die;

  return view('admin.products.view_products')->with(compact('products'));
}
```

To send data to your blade:

```
# Controller:
$data['category_name'] = $category_name;
$data['products'] = $products;
->withKeyName($data);

# Blade:
{{ $KeyName['category_name'] }}
{{ $KeyName['products'] }}
```

Comment: Thanks... but there is a problem .. i want to get a categorey name this code didn't show category name ..

Comment: @Muneeb What is the result of dd($category_name); ? Is there the name property?

Comment: public function viewProducts(){
      $products = Product::get();
      $products = json_decode(json_encode($products));
    
      foreach($products as $key => $val){
        $category_name = Category::where(['id'=>$val->category_id])->first();
            dd($category_name->name);
          if($category_name != null){
            $products[$key]->category_name= $category_name->name;
          }
        }
    //   echo "<pre>";print_r($products);die; 
    
      return view('admin.products.view_products')->with(compact('products'));
    }

Comment: dd($category_name->name); this code print the category name but how can i taransferd it to blade ..

Comment: @Muneeb just use this `return view('admin.products.view_products', compact('products')); `

Comment: @X4748 i didn't understand your editing answer can you edit full code ?

Comment: @Muneeb I just told you what to do! return view('admin.products.view_products')->withVARIABLENAME(['name' => 'x4748','product' [1,2,3,4]]);

Comment: @Muneeb Or `->with(['key' => ['name' => 'X4748','products' => 1,2,3,4]]);` and in your blade {{ $key['name'] }}